# FORTRAN array read behavior

Tags: fortran90

Suppose G is a (large) two-dimensional array. 
If I save the array by writing G to a text file as in:

```
  WRITE(1,*) G
```

and then later in a separate subroutine I try to recover by doing this:

```
  READ (1,*)  G
```

Will the READ statement keep reading all the lines of the text file until G is filled up with values?
Basically, how "smart" is this read statement in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  A list directed read statement will continue reading records until it has satisfied the list of input items or run out of file.